# How to make a BAT loop taskkill every 3 times it performs a task?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to make a BAT loop, but to perform taskkill every 3 times it opens google chrome.

I've tried to copy paste the code multiple times, but it opens only the first loop from the CSV file

This is my code:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.csv) do (
    start chrome "https:\\%%a"
    timeout 5
    taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
)
```

I just want it to run as it is now, but to perform taskkill every 3 times, not in every single time it goes to the browser

CSV content (I use Column A only):

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.instagram.com
```

repeated 300 times.

Comment: This is now your second question regarding the same task, in order for us to help you please click on the edit button below your question and add the content of the `C`omma `S`eparated `V`alues file in the same way as you added your code.

Comment: ok, sorry. I've edited the question

Comment: That is not CSV, also, in your previous question, you specifically mentioned in Column A. In this question, you also had used the [[tag:excel]] tag, and when you export a csv from Excel, it looks more like this: `"Column A","Column B","Column C"`. As you can see there's a marked difference, my example shows multiple doublequoted **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alues on a line. There is also usually a header line as at least the first line.

Comment: I use Column A only.

Comment: So when you export it from Excel, it doesn't doublequote each of those URL's?

Comment: No. I save it as comma seperated file

Comment: Where are the commas in your file content? and what are they separating?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the task on your own, and where are you stuck? Please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Also please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: > it opens only the first loop from the CSV file  -- what is "it"?  what does "opens" mean?  Loops cannot be opened.  There are no loops in CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an untested example, *I don't have a Windows PC and even if I did, I wouldn't use Chrome Browser*:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" "list.csv" 2^>NUL')Do @(
    Set /A LineNum=%%A %% 3
    Start chrome "https:\\%%B"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If !LineNum! Equ 0 (
        Timeout 5 /NoBreak
        TaskKill /F /IM chrome.exe
    )>NUL 2>&1
    EndLocal
)
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Is it possible to open each new tab with a 3 seconds delay? (no 3 seconds between 3 tabs, but 3 seconds between every single one)

Comment: @YairMatayev, yes it is! but as I have already answered your question and you've already stated that it works, you should not be changing your question, simply accepting my answer would be the appropriate action.